# Force distribution on corner supported plane

Tags: forces, moment, structural-beam

This question has been annoying me for a while. If you have a completely ridged rectangular plate of width and height x and y that is supported on each corner (A,B,C,D) and has force (F) directly in its center then I think the force on each corner support will be F/4.

[image]

What I want to know is how to prove this? Obviously there are 4 unknowns so we require 4 equations.

$$\sum F_z = 0$$

$$\therefore F_A+F_B+F_C+F_D=F$$
Also
$$\sum M = 0$$

Now taking the moments about point A 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{vmatrix}
        i & j & k \\
        x & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & F_B \\
        \end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
        i & j & k \\
        x & y & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & F_C \\
        \end{vmatrix}
+\begin{vmatrix}
        i & j & k \\
        0 & y & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & F_D \\
        \end{vmatrix}+
\begin{vmatrix}
        i & j & k \\
        x/2 & y/2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -F \\
        \end{vmatrix}=0
\end{equation*}
As the sum of moments equals 0, let i and j = 0
$$\therefore F_C+F_D=F/2$$ and $$F_B+F_C=F/2$$

Then taking the moments about another point to get 4th equation. But no matter what location I use the equations will not solve. I have been using a matrix to find $$F_A, F_B, F_C, F_D$$  See below. But when getting the det of the first matrix the answer is always equal to 0.

\begin{equation*}
\begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        ? & ? & ? & ? \\
        \end{vmatrix}
*
\begin{vmatrix}
        F_A \\
        F_B \\
        F_C \\
        F_D \\
        \end{vmatrix}
=\begin{vmatrix}
        1 \\
        0.5 \\
        0.5 \\
        ? \\
        \end{vmatrix}*F
\end{equation*}

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think most of us would spot immediately that symmetry requires all four forces be identical. Why would you attempt any more complicated treatment?

Comment: Also, Newton's Second Law both in its translational as well as its rotational version (each one in three possible spatial dimensions) should be incorporated. This means, in particular, all torques (around any particular corner) should add up to zero since the system is at equilibrium. But to do that you need to realize the free body diagram including all forces acting on your system in addition to F.

Comment: Ok, what about if the force $F$ was _not_ at the center, but at a distance $a$ from _DA_ and $b$ from _AB_? How would one derive the corner forces.

Comment: @JohnRennie I understand that the solution does appear immediately however I want to prove mathematically. What if there was more then one force?

Comment: @Benjamin I also tried this but still I could not get a solution.

Comment: @ja72  If the force wasn't in the center then in the sum of moments section above the x and y co-ordinates would change from (x/2, y/2) to what ever the position the force is in the plane.

Comment: I think this question should be re-opened since "most of us would immediately spot" a solution which is incorrect.

Comment: This problem is often given as a kind of object lesson. Under the assumptions of perfect rigidity it is under-constrained (as you have noticed) and one must invoke a symmetry argument to resolve the ambiguity. A resolution that does not rely on symmetry waits for the introduction of more physics (i.e. a stress-strain relationship at each of the supports (still assuming a planar sheet), or a flexing analysis in the supported sheet (assuming rigid supports) or both).

Comment: I'm voting to leave this closed because even if it the "immediately seen answer is incorrect," it's still a "do this work for me" homework question that we repeatedly agree is *not* the type of questions we want asked & answered on this site.

Comment: @KyleKanos Do you really think this is a "do-the-work-for-me" question?  The asker has done quite a bit of work already, got stuck in a corner, and asks "what [technically or conceptually] am I doing wrong?"

Comment: @rob: yes it is a do my work for me question, that is why I voted to close it and voted to leave it closed. The only question I see is "What am I doing wrong" which is synonymous with "do my homework for me." And even with the work and being stuck bit, we *still* repeatedly reject these types of questions as homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disproof by counterexample

Let's see if we can construct a counterexample to the fully-symmetric solution, where the forces at $A$ and $C$ are equal to each other and the forces at $B$ and $D$ are equal to each other but there is a different force on each diagonal, $A \neq B$.  Does such an arrangement exist where the rectangle is stable?

It does.  We can build it by changing our rectangle resting points to a rectangular table with springs for legs. Let's attach to each corner a spring with Hooke constant $k$, which exerts a restoring force $\vec F_H = -k\Delta\vec x$ when compressed by a distance $\Delta x$.  However due to some quality control issues at the spring factory we have two long springs, which we attach at the corners $A,C$, and two short springs which we attach at $B,D$.  Now we lower our table gently towards the level ground, keeping the table level.  What do the springs do as the distance between the table and the ground changes?

Clearly the long springs at $A,C$ touch the ground and begin to compress while the short springs at $B,D$ still dangle uselessly in the air.  This gives us an equilibrium configuration where the supporting force at $B,D$ is zero and the supporting forces at $A,C$ are not.  It's an *unstable* equilibrium, since any deviation of the weight of the table $F$ from the axis of rotation $AC$ will cause an unbalanced torque, but it's an equilibrium.

Now push down on the table some more, so that the legs at $B$ and $D$ also touch the ground.  You have forces at all four corners, but they are manifestly unequal:  the compression $\Delta x$ is greater for the long springs at $A,C$ than for the short springs at $B,D$.  This configuration *is* stable against small excursions of $F$ from the center of the rectangle --- and it gets stabler as the magnitude of $F$ gets larger.

I was planning to relate this to the [wobbly table theorem](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511490), a consequence of the Intermediate Value Theorem in calculus, but I got sleepy while writing.

### Disproof of uniqueness for forces supporting all four-legged tables

In fact it's relatively straightforward to argue that *any* four-legged support has this indeterminacy.  Here's an outline of the argument.

1. It's *possible* to support a plane at exactly three points.  The [engineering solution](http://www.newport.com/Optical-Mirror-Mount-Technology-Guide/1012753/1033/content.aspx) is use two of those points to define an axis of rotation and the third to define an orientation about that axis.  If you're more of a classical-mechanics person you can think of one point as defining the location of your object and the other two as specifying the two [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles).
2. Any rigid quadrilateral $ABCD$ supported at four points, if the weight force $F$ of the object is not on either of the diagonals $AB$ or $CD$, could therefore be supported just as well at only three of the points.  Therefore it is always possible to set the supporting force at one corner to zero.
3. If the supporting force $F$ does lie along one of the diagonals (without loss of generality: $AC$) we see from the construction above that the torques due to $B$ and $D$ must be equal, but we have no constraint on their magnitude.

Or in linear-algebra language: since the forces supporting a triangle are uniquely determined, the forces supporting a quadrilateral are always underdetermined.

Answer (score -1):

I think I have a solution.  Considering the corner forces $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ you have a system of 3 equations and 4 unknowns

$$\begin{align} 
 A + B + C + D & = F \\
 \frac{y}{2} \left(C+D-A-B\right) &= 0 \\
 \frac{x}{2} \left(A+D-B-C\right) & = 0 
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{vmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  -\frac{y}{2} & -\frac{y}{2} & \frac{y}{2} & \frac{y}{2} \\
  \frac{x}{2} & -\frac{x}{2} & -\frac{x}{2} & \frac{x}{2}
\end{vmatrix}
\begin{vmatrix} A \\ B \\ C \\ D \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} F \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{vmatrix} $$

What if consider the forces as deviation from $\frac{F}{4}$ such that

$$\begin{align}
  A &  = \frac{F}{4} + U \\
  B &  = \frac{F}{4} + V \\
  C &  = \frac{F}{4} + W \\
  D &  = \frac{F}{4} + G \end{align} $$

$$ \begin{vmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  -\frac{y}{2} & -\frac{y}{2} & \frac{y}{2} & \frac{y}{2} \\
  \frac{x}{2} & -\frac{x}{2} & -\frac{x}{2} & \frac{x}{2}
\end{vmatrix}
\begin{vmatrix} \frac{F}{4} \\ \frac{F}{4} \\ \frac{F}{4} \\ \frac{F}{4} \end{vmatrix} +
\begin{vmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  -\frac{y}{2} & -\frac{y}{2} & \frac{y}{2} & \frac{y}{2} \\
  \frac{x}{2} & -\frac{x}{2} & -\frac{x}{2} & \frac{x}{2}
\end{vmatrix}
\begin{vmatrix} U \\ V \\ W \\ G \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} F \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{vmatrix} $$

$$ \begin{vmatrix} F \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{vmatrix} +
\begin{vmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  -\frac{y}{2} & -\frac{y}{2} & \frac{y}{2} & \frac{y}{2} \\
  \frac{x}{2} & -\frac{x}{2} & -\frac{x}{2} & \frac{x}{2}
\end{vmatrix}
\begin{vmatrix} U \\ V \\ W \\ G \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} F \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{vmatrix} $$

$$ \begin{vmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  -\frac{y}{2} & -\frac{y}{2} & \frac{y}{2} & \frac{y}{2} \\
  \frac{x}{2} & -\frac{x}{2} & -\frac{x}{2} & \frac{x}{2}
\end{vmatrix}
\begin{vmatrix} U \\ V \\ W \\ G \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{vmatrix} $$

Now a possible solution is $U=0$, $V=0$, $W=0$ and $G=0$

I think to beyond this method, you need to assume a non-rigid frame, with some simple stiffness matrix, and in the end find the limit where $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: This is a good idea but shows another conclusion I was thinking could be an issue with the assumption it is completely rigid. In your last matrix equation the bottom two lines can be combined to show that V=G and U=W. You can also show that A=C and B=D. This would mean that the diagonals equal. So if this plate is completely rigid could there be a number of solutions as long as A=C and B=D?